# Samsung Galaxy a03 bypass

Tags: applications

I have tried to bypass my Samsung Galaxy A03, but found it hard to install the required downloaded apps in the phone when I was connected on the internet.

This is because the file shortcut app downloaded from galaxy store cannot display the apps by showing this message

> Please grant our app access to all your files. It might not work well without it.

Comment: Welcome to Android.SE. Just for clarity, is this about bypassing FRP?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you mean by "bypass" - there are multiple possibilities what you can bypass in a Smartphone: the factory reset protection Android mentioned, or the lock screen or on network level (routing) and so on.

Comment: try this tool (untested) https://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f162/mtk-client-tool-v5-2-a-2997980